# Find a number in a sequence using divide and conquer

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, graph, sequence

I have a sequence `A = [x1, x2,...,xn]` in which `x1 = 0` and `xk > xk-1` for each `k=2,3,...n`.
For example we can have [0, 2, 3, 5, 7]. In such sequence it turns out that:

- If `xc < c` then `xi < i` for each `1 <= i <= c` and,
- If `xc > c` then `xi > i` for each `c <= i <= n`

I want to find a number m which belongs to sequence such that `xm = m`.
Is it possible to implement such an algorithm using divide and conquer technique?

Comment: You want to find the "holes" in an increasing sequence; it's the problem of finding the missing numbers from a magazine collection. If slot 745 is occupied by number 746, you know that between 1 and 746 you missed one issue.

You can easily do this with bisection.

Answer (score 0):

This is the thing what `Binary Search` does. But just in divide and conquer technique.
Here are C++ code looks like -

```
int findNumber(int st, int ed, int tar, const vector<int> x) {
    if (st == ed) {
        if (x[st] == tar) return st;
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    int mid = (st + ed) / 2;
    if (x[mid] < mid) {
        return findNumber(mid+1, ed, tar, x);
    } else {
        return findNumber(st, mid-1, star, x);
    }
}
```

Call this method as `findNumber(0, x.size() - 1, tar, x)`